# No description for this method of Azure Cognitive Services SpeechRecognizer class

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

In my `Text to Speech` related code, I use [SpeechSynthesizer.SynthesisCompleted Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechsynthesizer.synthesiscompleted?view=azure-dotnet) of the [SpeechSynthesizer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechsynthesizer?view=azure-dotnet) of the [Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech?view=azure-dotnet) namespace to handle the scenarios when a speech is completed. I was looking for a similar event or method of the [SpeechRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer?view=azure-dotnet) class when working on `Speech to text` scenario - and I could not find any such event or method for the `SpeechRecognizer` class. The Microsoft document for [SpeechRecognizer.Finalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer.finalize?view=azure-dotnet) Method of [SpeechRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer?view=azure-dotnet) Class does not give any description of the method. I was wondering a) what is the role of this method b) the doc gives the syntax of the method as `~SpeechRecognizer ();`. What does the character `~` signifies here?

Comment: It is a [finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors).

Comment: @GuruStron You answered my question. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.